# How can I create createDrawerNavigator inside createStackNavigator in React native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using react-navigation v3 for react native app.
When I createDrawerNavigator inside createStackNavigator I can't openDrawer but if I createDrawerNavigator in root navigator I can open it.
Here is my code. Anyone have a solution for me?

**AppNavigator.js**

```
const AppNavigator =  createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    StackNavigatorMain: StackNavigatorMain,
    StackMenu: StackMenu
  },
  {
    headerMode: "null",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false
    },
    initialRouteName: "StackNavigatorMain"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**StackNavigatorMain.js**

```
const StackNavigatorMain = createStackNavigator(
    {   
        routeHome: Home,
        routeLogin: Login,
        routeForgotPassword: ForgotPassword,
        routeSignUp: SignUp,
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        initialRouteName: strings.routeHome,

    }
)
export default StackNavigatorMain
```

**StackMenu.js**

```
const StackMenu = createStackNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  MenuNavigator: MenuNavigator,
},
  {
    headerMode: "null",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false
    },
  }
);

export default StackMenu;
```

**MenuNavigator.js**

```
const MenuNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  Setting: Setting
},
  {
    drawerWidth: responsiveWidth(180),
    overlayColor: 'transparent',
    // drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
    contentComponent: AppSideMenu
  }
);

export default MenuNavigator;
```

**index.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
    );
  };
}
```

**Call open drawer onPress button in Component screen**

```
onClicked = () => {
        // props.navigation.openDrawer();
        props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
}
```

Comment: create drawer in stack or stack in drawer?

Comment: drawer in stack. How can I organize it, @m?